# I need two texts to be stacked using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need two texts to be stacked like this using CSS:

[image]

I tried this code:

```css
.sp-order {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.special-order>span {
  display: inline-block; 
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 2px;
  background: #f58220;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.special-order>span {
  background: #000000;
  color: #f58220;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-order">
  <span>Special </span>
  <span>Orders</span>
</div>
```

I’m getting some space between the two texts. Help me with this.

Comment: You don’t have a `.special-order` element. Spaces occur due to white space `Text` nodes between your elements or literal spaces within your elements.

Comment: Further to Xufox's comment: your selectors are wrong, you've used `.special-order` when, in your HTML, you appear to be using `.sp-order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```css
.sp-order {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sp-order>span:first-child {
  display:block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 2px;
  background: #f58220;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
.sp-order>span:last-child {
  background: #000000;
  color: #f58220;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-order">
  <span>Special </span>
  <span>Orders</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.sp-order {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

span.special {
  background: #000000;
    color: #f58220;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: 0 4px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.order {
   display: inline-block; 
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 2px;
  background: #f58220;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-order">
  <span class="special">Special </span>
  <span class="order">Order</span>
</div>
```

Comment: no order should not take full width. Kindly look at the image

Comment: Now it should fill its content.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your second CSS selector to `.sp-order>span`

```css
.sp-order {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sp-order>span {
  background: #000000;
  color: #f58220;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 12px;
}
.sp-order>span:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #fa0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-order">
  <span>Special </span>
  <span>Orders</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Both should align center.